# Replace a value in a multivalue dictionary list with another dictionary of same key

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I'm new to python been searching if I could get a similar method to do this, but they are too long just need a simple way of doing this.

I'm trying to find how I can substitute the 0 values in a multiple values dictionary with values of another dictionary that both have the same key. I'd like to avoid using index as there could be changes in the values also further calculation will be done with the output.

```
mydict = {'A': [20, 0, 15], 'B': [0, 5, 0], 'C': [15, 10, 10]}
mydict2 = {'A': 5, 'B': 3, 'C': 1}

output = {'A': [20, 5, 15], 'B': [3, 5, 3], 'C': [15, 10, 10]}
```

Thank you!!

**UPDATE**: the mydict2 was actually a nested list (lst) and I try using

d2 = dict((x['key'], x['val']) for x in mydict)
lst = [d2[x] for x in lst]
print d2

Error: string indices must be integers, not str.

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested list and dict comprehension along with a small test for `0` values:

```
{key: [x if x!=0 else mydict2[key] for x in vals] for key, vals in mydict.iteritems()}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked!! I didn't know you can do dict comprehesion like this.